# Excel same length but not align

Tags: excel

Please help on the pic
Same length but not align [image]

It is align in html page

Comment: What help do you need?

Comment: how to make the two string look align...They are in the same length,  but dont look like in the same physcial length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select a **monospace font** (also known as a fixed-length font) for both texts like `Courier New` and you will get both texts aligned:

[image: sample excel file]